# Jsoup with socks port

Tags: java, jsoup

How to use `Jsoup` via socks port?. I've not found anything in the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/).

```
Jsoup changelog:
   Release 1.9.1 [2016-Apr-16]
   Added support for HTTP and SOCKS request proxies, specifiable per connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 8080));
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").proxy(proxy).get();
```